# Using Puppeteer to load VueJS & Vuetify app

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuetify.js, puppeteer

I'm using puppeteer to create a PDF of an HTML page, which uses Vue & Vuetify:

```js
import { launch } from 'puppeteer';
.
.
.
const browser = await launch({ headless: false });
const page = await browser.newPage();
page.setContent(html, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
const pdf = await page.pdf({ format: 'A4' });
await browser.close();
return pdf
```

The HTML looks similar to this:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="app"> ... VUE & VUETIFY COMPONENT</div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.3.10/dist/vuetify.js" ></script>
    <script>
      const app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        vuetify: new Vuetify(),
        data() {} ..... 
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

However when the browser opens up, it looks like Vue & Vuetify haven't loaded properly.

Answer (score 0):

`<v-app>` is rendered with the `v-application` class, so you could use [`page.waitFor('.v-application')`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.1.1&show=api-pagewaitforselectororfunctionortimeout-options-args) to check that your app is ready:

```js
page.setContent(html);

await page.waitFor('.v-application');
// <v-app> assumed to be mounted here

const pdf = await page.pdf({ format: 'A4' });
...
```

Also be aware that your example seems to be missing important stylesheets that Vuetify requires. Don't forget to add them:

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my HTML string included some unrecognised characters, so thats why my Vue app was not rendering correctly.

Doing the following worked for me:

```
import { readFileSync } from 'fs';

const htmlString = readFileSync('path-to-html-file').toString();
  
page.setContent(htmlString, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });
```